# C1083: Cannot open include file: ... : No such file or directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a strange error C1083 (cannot the header file).  I've read other C1083 post, but I think my is different:

1)  The header file is added in my project properties under the additional includes property.

2)  Another class uses the same header (Same project), and it compiles.  The problem doesn't occur until I added my header file to the second header file.

3)  I use the auto complete/intellesense to make a "..\include\myClass.h" file.  One suggestion was the I was using the wrong path, but everything was in the same directory.  I tried it anyways.

All the files are in the same directory and that directory is included in the additional includes property.

In essence part of the project sees it but the other part doesn't?  I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. But in my case, maybe its because there is a circular dependency between the header I'm including and the included header (one is a template that receives the type of the other; and the other uses the template). The error "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'header.h': No such file or directory" however is a very bad output for this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target "include" directory is added to "additiona includes" project property, then you really **don't need** the path at all.

I mean, having:

```
\myFolder\project
                 \project.vcproj
                 \source
                      \myCode.cpp    <- compiling this one here?
                 \data
                      \myDb.foo
                 \include            <- this DIR#1
                         \foo1.h
                         \myClass.h  <- this FILE#1
                         \foo2.h
                         \lib1
                              \bar.h <- this FILE#2
```

if you added DIR#1 to "additional include directories", then:

```
#include "myClass.h"  // to include FILE#1
#include "lib1\bar.h"  // to include FILE#2
```

should be enough.

In case you not added the path there, the following should work:

```
#include "include\myClass.h"  // to include FILE#1
#include "include\lib1\bar.h"  // to include FILE#2
```

If you added the path and the first does not work, but the second one works, then you added the path incorrectly - make absolutely sure that the file/folder structure is really the same as you think it is. Also, if you added relative path to the project, try changing it to absolute.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that it's correct. I verified by changing it, the entire project breaks, not just this small spot.  In using your example, myClass.h is included in myCode.cpp, and everything compiles nicely.  But when I when I just include myClass.h in foo2.h, the compiler spits out errors.

Comment: @redDesert: I forgot to ask, how about including lib1\bar.h from myCode.cpp? does this work? it should.

Comment: @redDesert: now, to your comment - when including myClass.h from foo2, does the error claim that header file can't be found, or are there different errors then? if the former, try including lib1\bar.h if it succeeds - something is really screwed up, but nothing comes to my mind now. but if it fails, try adding "." (single period) to the "add. includes dirs". It's ugly patch, but might work.

Comment: OTOH, if the errors were different, then it might mean that the file actually **was found and included**, but that you've got some #include cycle in the headers, and/or your #define guards dont work, and myClass gets incorrectly included too early (i.e. before its dependencies) or multiple times (and clashes with itself).

Comment: I had a friend come by and look at this too.  I did not create this project, I'm am making some 'simple' modifications.  The #includes seem to be now all inner dependent/circular with my changes, which was not my original intention.  So I think you latter statement is on to something and I am already heading down that path.

Comment: @redDesert: When dealing with cyclic header references, the simplest way is to use #define/#ifndef "guardians" to ensure that the headers are included only once. This solves one problem, but leaves many more open. Most common one is FileA defines Foo and uses Bar, FileB defines Bar and uses Foo. Both try to #include the other. Cycle is broken by #define/#ifndef, cool. But still one of the files is "pulled as first", say FileA, and this results in pulling FileB and this FileB's references to Foo will be not resolved, since definitions from FileB gets compiled before the contents of FileA..

Comment: @redDesert: This problem can be solved with forward declarations and splitting/organizing the type definitions in a smarter way. Long long time ago I've [created a template](http://forum.4programmers.net/C_i_C++/162017-SOLVEDc++Klasy_zaprzyjaznianie_i_dostep_do_siebie?p=642607#id642607) that can help here. It's not perfect, but still is useful. Sorry for language, my native, I hadn't chance to translate it, but it's pretty straightforward (continued in next comment)

Comment: `MojaKlasa`=`MyClass`, `TutajZdefiniowana` = `defined here`, `TutajUzywanaPosrednio` = `indirectly used here`, `TutajUzywanaBEZPosrednio` = `DIRectly used here` (important emphasis); by "here" I meant "in this header file". Oh, and also: `toTezUzyciePosrednie` = `thisIsIndirectUsage`, `aToJestUzycieBezposrednie` = `thisIsDirectUsage`. ... I must finally find time and place to translate and update it eventually.

Comment: This template is not mandatory, but the point is that splitting #include into THREE parts (manual forward declarations, then required structural includes at top, then supplementary implementations at bottom) allows you to solve something like 97% percent of problems. Once you understand why it is so, the remaining 3% will be easy to solve - although they will need to break out of the scheme of this template.